# jQuery code to detect whether form fields have the default value when a checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

How could I rewrite this jquery code to compact it in a more elegant form:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[name="table_exist"]').click(function(){
      if($('input[name="table_name"]').val()=='users' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="table_name"]').val('');
   }
   else if($('input[name="table_name"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="table_name"]').val('users');
   }
   
   if($('input[name="user_id"]').val()=='user_id' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="user_id"]').val('');
   }
   else if($('input[name="user_id"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="user_id"]').val('user_id');
   }
   
   if($('input[name="user_name"]').val()=='user_name' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="user_name"]').val('');
   }
   else if($('input[name="user_name"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="user_name"]').val('user_name');
   }
   
   if($('input[name="user_email"]').val()=='user_email' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="user_email"]').val('');
   }
   else if($('input[name="user_email"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="user_email"]').val('user_email');
   }
   
   if($('input[name="user_pass"]').val()=='user_pass' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="user_pass"]').val('');
   }
   else if($('input[name="user_pass"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="user_pass"]').val('user_pass');
   }
   
   if($('input[name="joining_date"]').val()=='joining_date' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="joining_date"]').val('');
   }
   else if($('input[name="joining_date"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
   {
    $('input[name="joining_date"]').val('joining_date');
   }
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">

    <h2>DB Table</h2>

    <p>
     Activate the slider if you already have your own database table created!
    </p>

    <div class="inputCheckBox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="table_exist" />
    </div>

    <p>
     Edit here only if you have your own predifined table header names!
    </p>

    <div class="inputBox">
     <input type="text" name="table_name" value="users" required />
     <label>Table Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="inputBox">
     <input type="text" name="user_id" value="user_id" required />
     <label>User ID</label>
    </div>

    <div class="inputBox">
     <input type="text" name="user_name" value="user_name" required />
     <label>User Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="inputBox">
     <input type="text" name="user_email" value="user_email" required />
     <label>User E-mail</label>
    </div>

    <div class="inputBox">
     <input type="text" name="user_pass" value="user_pass" required />
     <label>User Password</label>
    </div>

    <div class="inputBox">
     <input type="text" name="joining_date" value="joining_date" required />
     <label>User Added Date</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="btn-install">
     Install
    </button>

   </form>
```

The whole process is to identify if the fields have the default values when a checkbox is unchecked. If the state is changed to checked then empty all fields to input custom information/values. If unchecked again it returns the initial values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're multiple ways to do that. You should use a loop.

I've wrote a small script, that would do the job. I do not know if the if block is correct but you should easily fix that with this base.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="table_exist"]').click(function(){
 var table_exist_checked = $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked');
 
 var fields = [
  'table_name',
  'user_id',
  'user_name',
  'user_email',
  'user_pass',
  'joining_date',
 ]; // Your field names
 
 // iterate over all fieldnames
 for(var index of fields) {
  var fieldName = fields[index]; // extract current fieldName
  var $elem = $('input[name="' + fieldName + '"]'); // save current element so we do not need to repeat
  
  // This is ur if-else. I do not exactly know if this is correct
   if($elem.val() == fieldName && table_exist_checked){
   $elem.val('');
  } else if($elem.val()=='' && !table_exist_checked){
   $elem.val(fieldName);
  }
 }
 
}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @ArayniMax example I fixed it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="table_exist"]').click(function(){

        var inputCheck = $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked');

        var fields = {
            'table_name': 'users',
            'user_id': 'user_id',
            'user_name': 'user_name',
            'user_email': 'user_email',
            'user_pass': 'user_pass',
            'joining_date': 'joining_date'
        };

        $.each(fields, function(key, value) {

            var fieldInput = $('input[name="' + key + '"]');

            if(fieldInput.val()==value && inputCheck)
            {
                fieldInput.val('');
            }
            else if(fieldInput.val()=='' && !inputCheck)
            {
                fieldInput.val(value);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help everyone!